# RxJava - Helper method to return previous result after executing Callable

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using the Single RxJava object and I want to run a void method in the critical path of the async workflow but return the previous result.

For example, I have something like:

```
Single<Integer> method() {
  Single<Integer> value = Single.just(10);
  return value.<RxJava Method>(Consumer<Integer> or Runnable<Integer>);
}

method().blockingGet();
```

returns

```
> 10
```

The stuff I do in `Consumer<Integer> or Runnable<Integer>`, I want to make sure happens before I return the value `10`. Is there a built in method in Single for this?

ie: I am just wondering if there is a cleaner way to portray:

```
Single<Integer> method() {
  Single<Integer> value = Single.just(10);
  return value.map(result -> {
    // call void method
    return result;
  });
}

method().blockingGet();
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `doOnSuccess`?

Comment: #doOnSuccess is fire and forget and could run concurrent to any other subscriber. I need to logic contained in the critical path.

Comment: What do you mean by "is fire and forget"? As far as I know `doOnSuccess` is equivalent to your example with `map`.